# Can we make our own Find My iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios7, icloud

I am thinking to make my own app like [Find My iPhone app](https://itunes.apple.com/au/app/find-my-iphone/id376101648?mt=8)  . But I am confused that whether apple allow developers to have access to play with the security or is there such Apple API's that can help us to include features as in the above app. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

Well I just can't comment because of low reputation. But people must give a reason to down-grade a question. Its quite a valid question.

Comment: Thanks for your support. Well if you have something helpful kindly share it.

Answer (score 3):

Creating an app like this is semi possible. Due to the fact that you are not allowed to keep running in the background, except for certain special cases. Such as Music or a guidance app (navigation apps)

Your app can register to receive updates from the GPS location and process them.
The problem is it will use your gps all the time.

The find my iphone app is a combination of wifi location/sim card location/gps location.

It uses a combination of all these items which it has to keep track of your location as close as possible. Now back to your question, the fact that you cannot keep running in the background, will mean the app needs to stay open all the time (open I mean running, not necessarily onscreen). Not like the application from apple itself, which of course is allowed to go outside these developer restrictions.

Comment: I don't think you'd need to keep the app running in the background with the iOS7 updates.

Comment: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4211 states the obvious that it would not work. A small quote from the article... " If you force an app to quit by dragging it up from the multitasking display, it won't be able to do its background activities, such as tracking location or responding to VoIP calls, until you relaunch the app. " which means you've lost the functionality.

Comment: I wasn't implying that they should be force quitting the app. But if you background the app by switching to a different app (or springboard) you should still be able to get Background Refresh working with APNS which would be able to send the location of the user to your server.

Comment: And thats what I was saying, that that doesn't work, because the app would not be actually in the background anymore. The only update an app can receive (when being closed closed, meaning not open at all) is from the APNS and this in its turn can not make your app initiate a network processed action. For that it must still be running in the background.

Comment: Ok, but what I'm saying is that nobody mentioned anything about force quitting the app.

Comment: Also, find my friends does not use your location unless someone requests the location. It doesn't send updates as you move. That is why you don't see all of your friend's locations at the same time.

Comment: He's talking about find my iphone isn't he? not find my friends... You're right about nobody saying anything about the quiting the app, but for the "find my iphone" isn't that the whole idea?!?!

Comment: Oh man, I didn't read this carefully enough. Sorry for the pointless argument.

Comment: Actually the mechanics may be the same. You can have a push notification sent to your alternate device which would then start the process of sending the location. Yes if you've killed the app forcefully this breaks down, but again, the mechanics should be the same.

Comment: That would defy the whole point then wouldn't it? If I lost my phone or it got stolen, the other person is not going to open that application to say where they are. The whole reason why this "find my iphone" app works is because it doesn't need to be opened.

Comment: Well if your phone is stolen, you remote wipe it. Right? Find my phone also works when the phone is just misplaced in the house as well. I think a lot of this depends on what OP's intentions are. 

Anyway, assuming OP didn't force quit and didn't remote wipe, the thief wouldn't need to take action and wouldn't know that the app was fired up in the BG by the remote push notification. 

I feel like we keep missing what each other is saying.

Answer (score 0):

The APIs exist for you to create the main functionality of this app. Core Location and APNS

1. When use A is looking for the location of user B, A would tell a server that it needs user B's location.
2. A push notification could fire up user B's app, at which point...
3. User B's location services would kick in, in the background,
4. Send this information to your server
5. Then update user A with another push notification.

Comment: would you please tell me the names of those APIs?

Comment: I described the wrong app. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947305/can-we-make-our-own-find-my-iphone-app/24965882?noredirect=1#comment38951207_24948333. Do you still want this info?